# Exact sequence and $S$-Noetherian module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian

Let $$ 0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0 $$ be an exact sequence of $R$-module. We know  that $M$ is Noetherian if and only if $M'$ and $M''$ are Noetherian. [Here](https://www.google.co.id/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjuz6rB293mAhU38XMBHTW9DvgQFjADegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww3.nd.edu%2F~ajorza%2Fcourses%2F2014f-m60210%2Fnotes%2Flecture33.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0_YLzEhqSod-0RP6qmRyYr), to prove that they use its ascending chain.

I want to prove that $M$ is $S$-Noetherian if and only if $M'$ and $M''$ is $S$-Noetherian. How to prove it? Should I also use ascending chain?

> **Definition** Let $R$ be a ring and $S\subseteq R$ a multiplicative subset. A right $S$-module $M$ is said to be $S$-finite if $Ms \subseteq F$ for some $s \in S$ and some finitely generated submodule $F$ of $M$, and $M$ said to be $S$-Noetherian if every submodule of $M$ is an $S$-finite module.

Comment: It isn't true that $M$ is Noetherian iff $M'$ and $M''$ are Noetherian.    You would need the sequence to additionally be right exact for that to be true.  The notes you mention state the result and proof correctly.

Comment: ^^ To expand on that, here's a way to trivially produce counterexamples.  Note that if $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is exact and $C \subseteq C'$ then $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C'$ is exact too.  So for example start with $R$ Noetherian and the usual short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow R \oplus R \rightarrow R \rightarrow 0$, think of any ring extension $R \subseteq R'$ with $R'$ not finitely generated as an $R$-module, and get the left exact $0 \rightarrow R \rightarrow R \oplus R \rightarrow R'$ where only $R'$ is not Noetherian.